# const reference to temporary variable does not work for std::function whose type does not match its declaration

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class Context {
public:
    Context(){
        field2values_["age"] = std::vector<int>{1,2,3};
    }

    const std::vector<int>& field2values(const std::string& field) const {
        auto it = field2values_.find(field);
        if (it == field2values_.end()) {
            return default_ints_;
        }
        return it->second;
    }

private:
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> field2values_;
    std::vector<int> default_ints_;
};

Context ctx;

std::vector<int> ctx_field2values(const std::string& field) {
    return ctx.field2values(field);
}

class Checker {
public:
    explicit Checker():
            user_field_values_(ctx_field2values),
            user_field_values_nc_(ctx_field2values)
    {}

    void print(){
        const auto& values = user_field_values_("age");
        std::cout << "size=" << values.size() << std::endl;  // unexpected: 18446744073709535740
        const auto& values_nc = user_field_values_nc_("age");
        std::cout << "size=" << values_nc.size() << std::endl;  // expected: 3
    }

private:
    const std::function<const std::vector<int>&(const std::string&)> user_field_values_;
    const std::function<std::vector<int>(const std::string&)> user_field_values_nc_;
};

int main() {
    Checker checker;
    checker.print();
}
```

As we all know, const reference to temporary variable will extend the its lifetime. But in the code above, it does not work for `user_field_values_` while it works for `user_field_values_nc_`. I guess this is because the type of `user_field_values_` does not match its initialization, namely `ctx_field2values`. But why is there such a difference? Can anyone explain in principle why this rule (const reference to temporary variable) does not take effect?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"const reference to temporary variable will extend the its lifetime."* not within constructors...

Comment: The return type is part of the `std::function` type, and for `user_field_values_` it just doesn't match that of `ctx_field2values`. It has nothing to do with references, temporaries or prolonging lifetime.

Comment: It is now explicit here: [class.base.init#8](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#8).

Comment: @Jarod42 Interesting, but aggregate init `struct foo { const int& d; }; foo f{42};` is still ok, right? `42` would then be alive for the rest of the function scope if I understand it correctly and returning `f` would make `f.d` a dangling reference.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In the implementation of std::function, ```user_field_values_``` should call the ```ctx_field2values```, so I think prolonging lifetime rule should apply here, which actually not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same reason the following produces a dangling reference:

```
int f() {
    return 42;
}

const int& invoke_f() {
    return f();
}

const auto& e = invoke_f(); // dangling!
```

Basically, when a temporary appears in a `return` statement, its lifetime is not extended. It gets destroyed at the end of the `return` statement. ([[class.temporary]/(6.11)](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6.11))

The function call operator of `user_field_values_` behaves just like the `invoke_f` above. It invokes `ctx_field2values` (which returns a `vector<int>`), and returns the result as a `const vector<int>&` -- a dangling reference.

In C++23, `std::function` will be able to recognize this pattern (by means of [`std::reference_converts_from_temporary`](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta.unary.prop#tab:meta.unary.prop-row-48)) and reject it. But it requires compiler support, which AFAIK does not exist yet.